# Glass bottle with a prolonged neck that continues into the inner space

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics, molding, glass

Is it possible to create following two shapes from glass using currently known glass mass production techniques?

Shape #1: bottle with a prolonged neck that continues into the inner space, like this (cross section):

```
     | |
     | |
    /| |\
   / | | \
  /       \
 /         \
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|___________|
```

Shape #2: same as shape #1 but with some circle holes in the the bottom, like this (cross section):

```
     | |
     | |
    /| |\
   / | | \
  /       \
 /         \
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|   _  _____|
```

I'm not a mechanical engineer, but intuitively it feels like extra holes might make the production easier/possible...

1. If such shapes can be produced using current glass mass production approaches - how much more expensive (in %) such a bottle would be compared to the same sized bottle with regular bottle neck? Is it merely the extra cost of extra glass?
2. If it is impossible to create such shapes in one step - can it be made in two steps? E.g.:

2.1 create two halves of the shape (cut in the middle as on the above picture) and press them together into one shape as long as they are still hot;

2.2 create the bottle (without bottleneck) and the bottleneck separately and then press them together into one shape as long as they are still hot.

I first thought it were impossible, but then I saw this:

http://www.sygmall.com/en/5021000-kitchenware/14284-creative-double-bottleneck-oil-bottle.html

which seems to be a more complex shape and that made me doubt...

Comment: How would you clean 1 properly?

Comment: @SolarMike the asker didn't ask how to clean it, just whether it could be produced.

Comment: @user253751 So can it?